# LDAP_route not working after upgrade from Debian Lenny to Wheezy

Tags: debian, ldap, sendmail

﻿
I have Debian 5 box (Lenny) with configured sendmail and LDAP_routing feature. This box is placed between Internet and my final mail server (MS Exchange). LDAP_route feture was used to validate recipients addresses against Exchange server and bounce messages sended to non-existing users. All have worked fine until I have updated this box to Debian 7 (Wheezy).

Now running "sendmail -bt" and issuing command "/map ldapmra address@mydomain.com" returns:

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> /map ldapmra address@mydomain.com
map_lookup: ldapmra (address@mydomain.com) Error getting LDAP results in map ldapmra: Operations error
no match (75)
```

while previously it returned (for valid address)

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> /map ldapmra address@mydomain.com
map_lookup: ldapmra (address@mydomain.com) returns address@mydomain.com (0)
```

or (for invalid address)

```
> /map ldapmra invalid_address@mydomain.com
map_lookup: ldapmra (invalid_address@mydomain.com) no match (68)
```

In my sendmail.mc file I have following lines:

```
FEATURE(`ldap_routing',, `ldap -1 -T<TMPF> -v mail -k proxyAddresses=SMTP:%0', `bounce')dnl

LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(`mydomain.com')dnl
define(`confLDAP_DEFAULT_SPEC', `-p 389 -h "myexchangeserver.mydomain.com" -d "CN=sendmail,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -M simple -P /etc/mail/ldap-secret -b "DC=mydomain,DC=com"')dnl
```

(to compile this file I have to replace new ldap_routing.m4 file (from sendmail 8.14.4) with version from old system (from sendmail 8.14.3)

What is wrong with my system? How can I restore previous behavior?

Any sugestions will be apreciated.

Comment: Check the /etc/ldap.conf files. You may be missing some info about the default DN on the server under which to search. The ldap parts of sendmail largely duplicate the ldapsearch command line. If you can get an ldapsearch command to work, then getting the sendmail config should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Check if the gollowing command/test gives more hints: `echo "/map ldapmra address@mydomain.com" | sendmail -d38.20 -bt`

Comment: Running echo "/map ldapmra address@mydomain.com" | sendmail -d38.20 -bt gives no more clues. Error message is almost the same as before. ie "Error getting LDAP results in map ldapmra: Operations error
no match (75)"

Comment: Ask your question at news:comp.mail.sendmail

Comment: From your Wheezy box can you LDAP query the Exchange server from the command line?

Comment: Yes, ldapsearch with equivalent options works fine.